# Combine rows property in java?

Tags: json

I am coming to an issue where I am trying to combine rows to look like my schema below. As of now, my json is returning three objects instead of returning one object.

Comment: I think you have some problems with DB design and the whole application design. Why your table has so many fields? Do you feel comfortable with that?

Answer (score 0):

ORA-00904: "AUTOCOMPLE0_"."HOURLY": invalid identifier and could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a].

This is a database error. It seems your table name doesn't match your entity name or the column name doesn't match the class attribute properly. To solve it, you should consider use explicit mapping in your AutoComplete JPA entity like this:

@Table(name="AUTOCOMPLETE") // the table name as in the database
public class AutoComplete {

@Column(name="HOURLY") // the correct table column name
private String hourly; // I have no idea of the type you are using for this attribute.
//...
}

Once you match properly, the class to the table name and the attribute to the column name, that error should go away.

You should post your AutoComplete class code here to get a better help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a column for each of theses 3 attributes in the table, you should make them transient:

```
@Transient
public String Hourly;
@Transient
public String Biweekly;
@Transient
public String Annual;
```

Comment: Also, you should use appropriate attribute type to each table column type. https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes

Comment: so, this not combine my rows shown in my schema above. @Carlos